# How to sort an Array based on another Array (in C)

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I have 3 arrays

```
char *model[10] = {"Honda ","Audi  ","Ferrari","Nissan","Toyota","Bugatti","Tesla ","Jensen","Porsche","Suzuki"};
    int price[10] = {750000,650000,950000,300000,900000,190000,400000,750000,300000,800000};
    int remain[10] = {3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,1,2};
```

I sorted the third array like this

```
void descendingOrder(){
    int i, j, a, b, c;
    for (i=0;i<10;++i) 
        {
            for (j=i+1;j<10;++j) 
            {
                if (remain[i]<remain[j]) 
                {
                    a=remain[i];
                    remain[i]=remain[j];
                    remain[j]=a;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now how can I sort the other two based on this array??

Been searching for 2 hours...

Comment: You don't! After sorting the 3rd array you lost the initial order and cannot apply same rearranging to the other arrays. Either sort all arrays at once or avoid using corresponding arrays at all. Use a string instead that holds all 3 fields and create an array of such struct.

Comment: You would make a single array of structs, the struct having members `char *model`,  `int price` and `int remain`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a struct of all three values would be the normal way but that does involve moving more data around. Sorting the remain array in the way you are doing loses information about the starting order. You could add another array, or better, add the starting order to the remain elements {{3,0}, {4,1}, {5,2}...etc then sort in descending order to {{8,6}, {7,5},..etc} then you can sort the other arrays putting element with index 6 in position 0, element with index 5 in position 1 etc.